# Installing mod_wsgi with pip install causes an error

Tags: python, django, apache, pip, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi so I can run my Django app with Apache.

However when I use `pip install mod_wsgi` I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_w59fztq\\mod-wsgi_5a0ae0135da94aadbb09b85297022451\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_w59fztq\\mod-wsgi_5a0ae0135da94aadbb09b85297022451\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mwvtbeia\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Include\mod-wsgi'
         cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_w59fztq\mod-wsgi_5a0ae0135da94aadbb09b85297022451\
    Complete output (24 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi
    copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\server
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\server\management
    copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\server\management
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\docs
    copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\docs
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mod_wsgi\images
    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_w59fztq\\mod-wsgi_5a0ae0135da94aadbb09b85297022451\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_w59fztq\\mod-wsgi_5a0ae0135da94aadbb09b85297022451\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mwvtbeia\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Include\mod-wsgi' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have no idea what the issue here could be..

Comment: What have you done to fix the very obvious error message _error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/_?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required